# Facebook, G+ Twitter - loading weirdly in Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, facebook, twitter-bootstrap

I just give this screenshot first:

[image]

bigger resolution: http://imagebin.org/303892

Scenario:

I have a "share" link ("teilen" in german). if you click, it must open a popover and in this popup there are facebook, g+ and twitter buttons as you see in screenshot. but the problem comes in FF, if I click on "teilen", first popover has buttons stacked over each other and only after second click they appear good. I see the error in console but dont know how to avoid this.

my html for popover is:

```
<div id="smpopover" style="display: none;height: 40px">
     <table>
       <tr>
         <td><div class="fb-like" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div><br /> </td>
         <td><div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium" data-annotation="none"></div></td>
         <td><a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-text="Interessantes Thema auf www.Bibago.de:" data-lang="de">Twittern</a>
         </td>
       </tr>
     </table>           
</div>
```

**EDIT**:

i changed `display:none` to `visibility:hidden`. now everything is working fine, but only in Mac FF nothing changed to good. any ideas?

Comment: are you using bootstrap

Comment: @IPADDRESS, yes. i am using bootstrap.